# Merge 2 JSON Files Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, json.net

I have 2 json files, or String and i want to merge them based on ID. Like join on sql. This is the example:

This is Json 1:

```
{
    "City": [{
        "CityId": 9,
        "CityName": "Kukes"
    }, {
        "CityId": 18,
        "CityName": "Tirana"
    }, {
        "CityId": 19,
        "CityName": "Vlore"
    }, {
        "CityId": 22,
        "CityName": "temp"
    }]
}
```

And this i json 2:

```
{
    "Citizen": [{
        "CitizenId": 38,
        "CitizenLastName": "Bale",
        "CitizenName": "Christian",
        "City_Id": 19
    }, {
        "CitizenId": 39,
        "CitizenLastName": "ttrtrt",
        "CitizenName": "test",
        "City_Id": 18
    }, {
        "CitizenId": 42,
        "CitizenLastName": "Freeman",
        "CitizenName": "Morgan",
        "City_Id": 9
    }, {
        "CitizenId": 43,
        "CitizenLastName": "Snow",
        "CitizenName": "Jon",
        "City_Id": 9
    }, {
        "CitizenId": 44,
        "CitizenLastName": "test2",
        "CitizenName": "test",
        "City_Id": 9
    }]
}
```

I want it to merge in a json file or string based on id like this structure:

```
{
    "City":
    [
        {
            "CityId":9,
            "CityName":"Kukes",
            "Citizens" : [{"CitizenId":42,"CitizenLastName":"Freeman","CitizenName":"Morgan","City_Id":9},{"CitizenId":43,"CitizenLastName":"Snow","CitizenName":"Jon","City_Id":9},{"CitizenId":44,"CitizenLastName":"test2","CitizenName":"test","City_Id":9}]
        },
        {
            "CityId":18,
            "CityName":"Tirana",
            "Citizens" : [{"CitizenId":39,"CitizenLastName":"ttrtrt","CitizenName":"test","City_Id":18}]
        },
        {
            "CityId":19,
            "CityName":"Vlore",
            "Citizens" : [{"CitizenId":38,"CitizenLastName":"Bale","CitizenName":"Christian","City_Id":19}]
        },
        {
            "CityId":22,
            "CityName":"temp",
            "Citizens" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried all day and still found nothing. Do you have any idea how to do this with Newtonsoft? Or any other way? But I'd like it with newtonsoft.

Comment: You could create c# object representations of your JSON and have Newtonsoft put the JSON strings into the objects, then use LINQ to perform your join into a new object, and finally use Newtsonsoft to re-serialize your new object back to JSON.

Comment: That's a great requirement.  So, what happened with your code when you were working on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm), using [`ToLookup()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) to find all citizens for a given city:

```
var cities = JToken.Parse(cityJson);
var citizens = JToken.Parse(citizenJson);

var lookup = citizens.SelectTokens("Citizen[*]").ToLookup(c => (string)c["City_Id"]);

foreach (var city in cities.SelectTokens("City[*]"))
{
    city["Citizens"] = new JArray(lookup[(string)city["CityId"]]);
}
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D7GZLb).

To load your JSON from a file, then later save back, see [Read JSON from a file](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJson.htm) and [Write JSON to a file](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/WriteToJsonFile.htm).